# Как штатным методом hsqldb почистить mem.* полученые от тестов?

Tags: java, hsqldb

Я использую `hsqldb` библиотеку для тестирования DB. В процессе прохождения тестов в корне проекта создается три файла и папка: `mem.log`, `mem.properties`, `mem.script` и `mem.tmp`.

Как штатными методоми `hsqldb` удалить эти файлы из директории сразу после прохождения тестов, или еще лучше отказаться от их создания? Возможно есть способ указать параметр в `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem;sql.enforce_size=false</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping resource="ru/pravvich/model/User.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="ru/pravvich/model/Propose.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: попробуй добавить в конец `connection.url` параметр `shutdown=true`

Comment: @Nikolay если так `<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem;sql.enforce_size=false;shutdown=true</property>` то не работает. Так `;sql.shutdown=true` тоже